# Ajax/Json contact form is not working on this particular server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have this landing page with contact form which is working without any problems on my regular hosting but It doesn't want to work on this VPS I was given access to. When I click "Send" button nothing is happening and email is not being sent.  I checked mail() function and it seems to work on their server.

What could be the reason for ajax/json not working on this server?

Here's the JS code (core.js):

```
if ($('#contact').is(":visible")) {

    $("#contact button").click(function() {

        var name     = $("#contactname").val();
        var message  = $("#contactmessage").val();
        var email    = $("#contactemail").val();
        var emailReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})?$/;

        // client-side validation
        if(emailReg.test(email) == false) {
            var emailValidation = false;
            $('#contactemail').addClass("error");
        }
        else
            $('#contactemail').removeClass("error");

        if(name.length < 1) {
            var nameValidation = false;
            $('#contactname').addClass("error");
        }
        else
            $('#contactname').removeClass("error");

        if(message.length < 1) {
            var messageValidation = false;
            $('#contactmessage').addClass("error");
        }
        else
            $('#contactmessage').removeClass("error");

        if ((nameValidation == false) || (emailValidation == false) || (messageValidation == false))
            return false;

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "send-email.php",
            data: $("#contact").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {

                $('.form').html('<p class="success">Email sent. Thank you.</p>');

            }
        });
        return false;
    });

};
```

The PHP file (**send-email.php**):

```
<? if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" ) {

    $destination = 'myemail@example.com'; // change this to your email.

    $email   = $_POST['email'];
    $name    = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = $name;
    $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n" .
             "Reply-To: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n" .
             "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
             "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
             "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\r\n" .
             "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";

    mail($destination, $subject, $message, $headers);

}
```

And HTML:

```
<form class="contact" id="contact">
  <div class="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="contactname" />
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="contactemail" />
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" id="contactmessage"></textarea>
    <button>Send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: So then you make a test email php script...and the email was send, right?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors in your browser?

Comment: also you could put an error function on your ajax call like `error: function(a, b, c) { alert(c); }`  That might give you a hint of whats going wrong

Comment: Robert Rosaz: yes, test email php script worked.

Comment: right after the success function closing bracket put a comma then the error function that I have a above

Comment: @Jacob I get this error `SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'`

Comment: Fixed it.. just added "<?php" instead of "<?" inside the php file.  Thanks @Jacob

Answer (score 0):

The statement `var emailValidation = false;` inside `IF` is makes the variable `emailValidation` local to it. Similarly other variables too are local. Declare them in global scope, outside the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$("#contact").serializeArray()
```